# Installing LaravelCollective in 5.5.*

Tags: laravel-5.5

On `xampp`,While installing `laravelcollective` in `Laravel 5.5`.* version  i got an error saying:-

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
```

Could not parse version constraint :`5.5.`*: Invalid version string ":`5.5.`*"

I had used composer require `"laravelcollective/html":"^5.5.`" in terminal  for installing it 
How to fix this problem?

Comment: You can check the instructions here https://www.5balloons.info/installing-laravel-collective-package-on-laravel-5-5/

Comment: where did you even see that package at the version to know to type that at all?

Answer (score 1):

Open your composer.json file and add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.0",` manually

(Try this `5.4.0` version. As I know there is no laravel collective version like `'5.5.'` )

Should be;

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",

        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.6",
        "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0" //here
    },
```

Then say composer update, it should works

Answer (score 0):

Open your composer.json and following changes on

```
  "require": {
       "php": ">=7.0.0",
      "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
      "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
      "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
       "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
      "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5" //here
   },
```

then update your composer as "composer update".

My result on

```
Updating symfony/css-selector (v5.1.5 => v5.1.6): Loading from cache
    Updating nikic/php-parser (v4.10.0 => v4.10.2): Downloading (100%)
    Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.5.4): Downloading (100%)
```

while composing.... success.!